# Android: Can listviews dynamically update the UI output when the database it's binded to changes?

Tags: database, android, listview

I have a database that gets updated by a background thread. Is is possible for the UI ouput(using a listview) to change when a database entry is added/deleted? I've seen examples of using `SimpleCursorAdapter` and `listViewAdapters` and I'm not sure which to use and if it would even work.

I found an "efficient" listViewAdapter which would work great for me since it doesn't call findViewById often and I can change the data structure to hold exactly what I need, but I don't know how to hook it into my database adapter so it dynamically updates the output when there is a database change. Example: http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/125/

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, and call `requery()` on the `Cursor` as needed. That will fetch the latest data and will update the associated `ListView`.

Comment: Who would call requery()? If the user is already viewing the list onscreen and the background thread adds an entry, I wanted the list to be refreshed. Would my dbAdapter call it after it modifies the DB thus refreshing the currently displayed listview? I have the above linked example retrieving and displaying items from my DB, but I know it won't dynamically update my output while viewing the list. Stinks because I spent a little time modifying the code to work with my DB entries and now I'm not sure if I have to scrap all that work.

Comment: The background thread needs to alert the UI: "yo, dude, there's a data change, please requery()".